# Does shell echo complete content without escape character

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My shell script is following:

```
#!/bin/bash
account0=0xf2de2e86b9b634f655e441a4e8353c9bf59352d7
passwd=123456
data={"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","id":1,"params":[$account0,$passwd]}
echo $data
```

My expected is (NOTICE "):

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","id":1,"params":[0xf2de2e86b9b634f655e441a4e8353c9bf59352d7,123456]}
```

NOT

```
{jsonrpc:2.0,method:personal_unlockAccount,id:1,params:[0xf2de2e86b9b634f655e441a4e8353c9bf59352d7,123456]}
```

:
And I **do not** want to use **escape character**, how ?
like content insert into xml tag "`<![CDATA[..."..]]>`"

Comment: "Do not want to use escape character" -- when it comes to quoting, you don't have a choice (well, you have plenty of choices about *how* to quote, but you don't have a choice to write an arbitrary literal without any kind of quoting or escaping at all, unless you put it in a separate file that isn't parsed as source -- even putting something in a quoted heredoc, the beginning and end of that heredoc constitute quoting boundaries). You can't write an arbitrary string in Python or C or Java without any kind of quote character; why do you expect to be able to write one in shell that way?

Comment: Just to be sure this is clear, btw -- `echo` *has nothing at all to do with how your `data` string is parsed*. By the time `echo $data` runs, `data` already has a value assigned, and `echo` has no possible way of knowing what the literal line of code that parsed to or otherwise assigned that value was.

Comment: Now, if you *don't* quote `$data`, then the value gets string-split and glob-assigned before being passed to `echo`, which has potential to corrupt it a bit -- but `echo "$data"` passes `echo` the *precise* contents of the `data` variable, and whereas `echo` *can* munge your value in unwanted ways, the set of unwanted things that compliant implementations are prone to do (described in the link at the end of my answer) don't include quote removal; by the time `echo` is invoked, quote removal already happened or didn't, and it's too late to change.

Comment: like GOLANG, `` could deal with the quote instead of escape character

Comment: If all you want is a kind of quotes that you can put a literal JSON string in with no escaping (save in the case where the JSON includes a string with a literal single-quote itself), that's already included my answer -- `'` does the Right Thing.

Comment: @Charles Duffy but when I use the jq, it will append \" ,

Comment: ```memberStr=$(jq -cn --arg memberStr "$memberStr" '
{"contractManagerAddress":"0x1122d6391338dd43e20741f880f76fa6d9743713","member":{"id":1,"name":"neteasetest1","type":"Enterprise","privilege":"SendTxAndMineBlock","maxMinerNodesCount":100}}
')
echo "$memberStr"

data=$(jq -cn --arg memberStr "$memberStr" '
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"consortiumchain_addOrUpdateMember","id":3,"params":[$memberStr]}
')
echo "$data"```

Comment: it output : ```{"contractManagerAddress":"0x1122d6391338dd43e20741f880f76fa6d9743713","member":{"id":1,"name":"neteasetest1","type":"Enterprise","privilege":"SendTxAndMineBlock","maxMinerNodesCount":100}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"consortiumchain_addOrUpdateMember","id":3,"params":["{\"contractManagerAddress\":\"0x1122d6391338dd43e20741f880f76fa6d9743713\",\"member\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"neteasetest1\",\"type\":\"Enterprise\",\"privilege\":\"SendTxAndMineBlock\",\"maxMinerNodesCount\":100}}"]}```

Comment: but my expected : ```{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"consortiumchain_addOrUpdateMember","id":3,"params":[{"contractManagerAddress":"0x1122d6391338dd43e20741f880f76fa6d9743713","member":{"id":1,"name":"neteasetest1","type":"Enterprise","privilege":"SendTxAndMineBlock","maxMinerNodesCount":100}} ]}```

Comment: The obvious problem above is that `memberStr` is a **literal string**, but you're treating it like JSON data. So of course jq escapes it. If you don't want that, tell jq it's JSON, not a string.

Comment: ...waitaminute, though -- that wasn't present in your original question. Editing a question after it was first asked in a way that invalidates prior answers is not welcome here; you should be asking a completely new question with only the content that wasn't covered in your original question (and accordingly answered) -- which is to say, after you've received a credible answer, further question edits should be for clarity, not extensions. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal

Comment: ...that said, as a hint that might prevent that extra question from needing to be asked, if content you're passing is JSON, use `--argjson`, not `--arg`.

Comment: thank u very much! you solve my problem

Comment: @JimGreen, besides putting the entire line in single quotes, do the same for the variables: `data='{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","id":1,"params":['$account0','$passwd']}'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `echo` isn't your problem. (It's *a* problem, but not your *immediate* problem).

Your problem is that your quotes aren't being assigned to the variable at all. Quotes are *syntax* to bash; it reads them as part of the instructions on how to parse a string. Consequently, they're consumed by bash itself, and not assigned as a value unless they are themselves quoted or escaped.

---

To make the whole thing literal, you can put the entire line in single quotes:

```
data='{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","id":1,"params":[$account0,$passwd]}'
echo "$data"
```

...or you can generate it with a heredoc, at some cost to efficiency:

```
{ IFS= read -r -d '' data || [[ $data ]]; } <<'EOF'
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","id":1,"params":[$account0,$passwd]}
EOF
echo "$data"
```

Assuming you want to perform expansions, replacing `account0` with the name of the like-named shell variable, the *wrong* way to do it is to switch from a single-quoted context to a double-quoted context before your variables are referenced:

```
# BAD: Does not guarantee result is valid JSON
account0=exampleName; passwd=examplePassword
data='{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","id":1,"params":["'"$account0"'","'"$passwd"'"]}'
echo "$data"
```

...or to switch to an unquoted heredoc (using `<<EOF`, not `<<'EOF'`):

```
# BAD: Does not guarantee result is valid JSON
account0=exampleName; passwd=examplePassword
{ IFS= read -r -d '' data || [[ $data ]]; } <<EOF
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","id":1,"params":["$account0","$passwd"]}
EOF
echo "$data"
```

And the *right* way to do it is to use `jq` to generate safely-escaped JSON containing your literal values:

```
# GOOD: Result will always be syntactically valid JSON.
account0=exampleName; passwd=examplePassword
data=$(jq -cn --arg account0 "$account0" --arg passwd "$passwd" '
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_unlockAccount","id":1,"params":[$account0,$passwd]}
')
echo "$data"
```

---

And remember where I said `echo` is a problem, even if it's not your immediate problem? See the APPLICATION USAGE section of [its POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) to understand why it's innately unreliable when handling arbitrary data, keeping in mind that bash can be configured at runtime to behave according to any of the variants described in that spec. Use `printf '%s\n' "$foo"` instead of `echo "$foo"` to get consistent and reliable behavior.

Comment: Or, to use a quoted heredoc with `cat`: `read data << \EOF\nblah\nEOF`

Comment: @WilliamPursell, good call. (And, err, you mean "without", right?). I've adopted that to support multi-line strings.